# How NetSuite reconciles bank statement from technical point of view?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

In Netsuite, I am trying to create a custom bank reconciliation tool for a client.

Suppose I want to reconcile my bank statement with some bill record using the native netsuite reconciliation functionality. To be clear say there are 2000 Bill records in NetSuite. I upload the bank statement and netsuite shows there are 4 bills that are remaining reconciliation that can be mapped with the statement.

**My question is how netsuite knows that 1996 are already reconciled and 4 are still remaining.**

**I did not find any flag/field in the bill record that mentions whether that record has been reconciled or not.**